# Write event types from same Kafka topic to different S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I have a requirement where I will get JSON messages (with different schemas) to same Kafka topic. However, when syncing to S3, I have to write to different folders to S3 based on schema.

Could you please let me know how to do this in Kafka Connect? I'm looking at Single message transaction but not able to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Avro Serialiser?

As far as you have deserialised object, you can decide what is the schema is.

```
if( typeof(yourMessage) == YourModelType1 ) {
    
}
else if( typeof(yourMessage) == YourModelType2 ) {
    
}
```

Comment: `typeof`? You can't make Kafka Connect do this logic since its Java based

Comment: @OneCricketeer, am not using any serialised/deseralizer. Trying to see if this can be achieved through properties.

Comment: @OneCricketeer,
I am here using C#. There should be similar in Java. Just want to show a generic way to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Buckets cannot be changed. Prefixes within a bucket (what you refer to as "folders") can, but only if you have field information in the value of the record.

e.g. some example data

```
{"type": "data1", "payload": {...}}
{"type": "data2", "payload": {...}}
```

With these configs

```
partitioner.class=FieldPartitioner
partition.field.name=type
```

Should write to S3 as

```
s3://bucket/type=data1/topic-partition-offset.json
s3://bucket/type=data2/topic-partition-offset.json
```

If the `type` field isn't available, then you will need to write a custom SMT that can inspect each of your records to determine what type it will be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will help to write to to sub-folders within an S3 bucket. Wondering whether will this lead to small files when we have the property 'flush.size=100000'. If 1 type has 99K messages and other type has just 1K message..then a small file would be created for the type that has 1K messages. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.